# Damage [Countable / Uncountable]

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As you are well aware,

> Compensate someone for something 
> means: reimbursing someone for something they have e.g. lost.
> For instance we say: 
> Compensate someone for **damage**: 
> **Example:** The insurance company will compensate **people** for the **damage** .

But concerning:

> Claim for damage**s**: 
> Meaning: if a court of law awards damages to someone, it orders money to be paid to them by a person who has damaged their reputation or property, or who has injured them.

But, the question is that, why "damage" is used in an uncountable form in the first case (compensate someone for **damage**,) while it is used in a plural form in the second case (claim for **damages**,) while the noun [damage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/damage) is an uncountable noun?!

I was wondering if you could help me with this question.

Comment: As your second quote suggests it is a technical term used in a legal context. I have no idea why so this is posted as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: Did you not understand uncountable means the word as a noun implies ALL damage?

Comment: I didn't follow you @GWarner. May I ask you to clarify your intent?

Comment: I likely misunderstood what was actually being asked. Why the word 'damage' is used in the first place, or what does uncountable mean.

Comment: I beg your pardon @GWarner! Your statements are all Greek to me and I cannot make anything out of them. I think the question is quite clear and regarding countable / uncountable nouns I refer you to an online dictionary portal.